# Adding Static Library to xcode not working

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, static-libraries, .a

I added a static Library and its header file to my OSX project and added them to Link Binary With Libraries under Build Phases.

Xcode gives me the following warning

ignoring file /Users/sd1212/Desktop/OpenGLPlugin/libClientLib.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

and wont let me call any of the library methods.  I thought I had an architecture problem, so I looked online... Maybe the instructions weren't clear or something, but I think that I already have the x86_64 architecture added, and I changed "Build Active Architecture only" to "No."

Here is a screen shot of the project's architecture settings

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Please help!  Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you could be correctly quoting that warning, in the `for   archive` part.

Comment: @JWWalker  Maybe its because I made it code?  Weird.. fixed.

Comment: I meant that I thought it would say `for architecture x86_64` or something like that.

Comment: @JWWalker I copied and pasted the error.  I guess that confuses me also?  Probably something screwed up in the xcode build settings and I won't be able to find what.  I'll just add the library to a new project and move my files there... I hate myself

Comment: @JWWalker Yes, thats what I thought it would say as well.  I made a new Xcode project, and that's the error I am getting now.

Comment: OK, now you know that it's the project that *builds* the library that you really need to look at.

Comment: @JWWalker What should I be looking for?

Comment: Same thing you looked for here, what architecture is being built.

Comment: @JWWalker You were right, the build settings were off... Thanks for your help.  Submit an answer so I can pick it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the project that builds the static library, as well as the project that links to it, and make sure they both build the right architecture.  Consider not only the Valid Architectures line, which you highlighted in your screen shot, but also the Architectures setting.  The ones that get built are the ones in both lines.